# Using sleep() to create a function that consistently loops every second

Tags: python, loops, sleep

I have a program that needs to execute every second. However I am concerned that the code would add a slight delay in turn causing it delay slightly longer then intended. Sample code:

```
while True:
    print(time)
    sleep(1)
```

In my case I will be adding more complicated function calls in this loop and am concerned that they will mess with my timer. Should I even be worried, and or is there another way for me to ensure this function loops every second?

Comment: You could use a library like [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import threading

def scheduleFunc():
  threading.Timer(1.0, scheduleFunc).start()
  print(time)
```

Or use this:

```
import sched, time

scheduled = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def scheduleFunc(sc): 
    print(time)
    scheduled.enter(60, 1, scheduleFunc, (sc,))

scheduled.enter(60, 1, scheduleFunc, (scheduled,))
scheduled.run()
```

Comment: This worked for me